# How can I test my spamfilter under real world conditions?

Tags: email, spam

We are currently planning to migrate our outsourced mail solution to our own servers. The last thing we need to test is the spam filter. We are going to use a cloud based spam and anti virus filter provided by Microsoft.

We now have a test server with an assigned test domain. We now want to test the spam filter under real world conditions. We thought about adding some test addresses to "no spam" lists to verify if the cloud based service is doing what it should. Is this a good idea or are there better solutions beside using our real mail server for validation of that service?

Comment: Also take a look at this answer on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/a/126185

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to test your spam-filter is by actually spamming it yourself. Try to spam it yourself by using the techniques spammers use, on smaller scale. If your protection works on small scale, you can also assume it works on bigger scale.

There are also various of tools which allow reliable testing:

- [SpamAssasin - GTUBE](http://spamassassin.apache.org/gtube/)
- [EmailSecurityCheck](http://www.emailsecuritycheck.net/)
- [Litmus](https://litmus.com/spam-filter-tests)

Especially GTUBE (Generic Test for Unsolicited Bulk Email) is often used and works similar like EICAR for testing Anti-Virus setups.

However, lot of those filters also work with blacklisting. So the best testing-method is throwing your service online and see if you receive real-world spam.